# Confused between posting on Code Review, Software Engineering, or Stack Overflow

Tags: support, scope

I have this questions that fits the FAQ of [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour/), [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour/), and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It contains a couple code snippets for one platform and I'd like to know the recommended practice between them. I know Stack Overflow would accept this question, but where should I best fit it?

Comment: Did you write this code?

Comment: Yes. It's a concatenated sample from my actual code.

Answer (score 13):

Stack Overflow is for concrete problems; if it's somehow not working as intended.

Code Review is for code that works as intended, but could use improvements - to performance, to maintainability, or other goals.

Software Engineering is for the conceptual questions.

(I recall there's a diagram about that, but have been unable to find it back).

Since you have actual snippets, I'd say it's Stack Overflow for the things that are broken and Code Review for the things that need improvement.
Note that you don't have to do this "in parallel". You may ask Stack Overflow to help fix things first. And after that, post the larger, fixed codebase to Code Review.

I don't think Software Engineering is where you want to go, unless you want to re-consider the entire design.

Comment: Both versions work fine and achieve the same thing. What I'm looking for is performance behind the methods.

Comment: Two versions, both working fine? Sounds like CodeReview to me then.

Comment: Well, I've posted it on Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/18255/16963